# non-Javascript country-province selection

Tags: javascript, html, forms, unobtrusive-javascript

How should I go about country and province selection in a HTML form when JavaScript is disabled?

I would normally add a disabled province select field with javascript, and when the user selects some country, ajax loads the provinces. But how can I allow users to pick a province without javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a button (other than the submit button) which posts the form back to the server.

You could have a button "Display provinces" after the country drop-down, which posts back the form to the server. On the server, you retrieve the country of the (incomplete) form, and then add the appropriate provinces to the province dropdown.
The user then can select the province and hit the submit button.

When javascript is present, you may hide the button with javascript and do it all with ajax.

Answer (score 1):

choose a conntry, press a button, reload the page with a GET parameter, render the page using php and show the province for that state

Comment: But if you reload the page with a GET parameter, you'll lose all the data of the other fields of the HTML form. I don't think that round-trip is necessary.